# Insert Same Data Every 6th & 7th Row - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have the following plus a whole lot more in an excel spreadsheet:

```
 service instance 404 ethernet
   description Name 661-1-11-3-15
   encapsulation dot1q 804 second-dot1q 4
   rewrite ingress tag pop 2 symmetric
   bridge-domain 804 split-horizon

  service instance 405 ethernet
   description Name 661-1-11-4+1
   encapsulation dot1q 804 second-dot1q 5
   rewrite ingress tag pop 2 symmetric
   bridge-domain 813 split-horizon

  service instance 408 ethernet
   description Name 661-1-12-1-4
   encapsulation dot1q 804 second-dot1q 8
   rewrite ingress tag pop 2 symmetric
   bridge-domain 823 split-horizon
```

I am needing to make it look like the following:

```
 service instance 404 ethernet
   description Name 661-1-11-3-15
   encapsulation dot1q 804 second-dot1q 4
   rewrite ingress tag pop 2 symmetric
   bridge-domain 804 split-horizon
   service-policy input platinum-up
   service-policy output platinum-dn

  service instance 405 ethernet
   description Name 661-1-11-4+1
   encapsulation dot1q 804 second-dot1q 5
   rewrite ingress tag pop 2 symmetric
   bridge-domain 813 split-horizon
   service-policy input platinum-up
   service-policy output platinum-dn

  service instance 408 ethernet
   description Name 661-1-12-1-4
   encapsulation dot1q 804 second-dot1q 8
   rewrite ingress tag pop 2 symmetric
   bridge-domain 823 split-horizon
   service-policy input platinum-up
   service-policy output platinum-dn
```

Basically two rows of data ('service-policy input platinum-up' & 'service-policy output platinum-dn') and a blank row would be inserted for every blank row between each dataset.  Can someone show me an easier way of inserting the data other than by inserting 2 blank rows and copying the data into the blanks?

Thanks,
J. R.

Comment: Quite honestly, there are plenty of ways of doing this, but if you simply record a macro doing exactly what you said (insert rows and enter the data) on one set with (**Hint:** Use relative references), you can put it in a loop and you'd proabably have a fast and easy solution....

Comment: OR, since you know it's already every 5th row, you can use a `For Loop with Step 5`...

Comment: There's 6 rows for every set (5 lines + a blank), plus you need to add 2 to account for the ones you just inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple.

```
Sub InsertLines()
    Dim Row As Long
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Row = 6
    Do
        Range(Cells(Row, 1), Cells(Row + 1, 1)).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Cells(Row, 1).Value = "  service-policy input platinum-up"
        Cells(Row + 1, 1).Value = "  service-policy output platinum-dn"
        Row = Row + 8
    Loop Until Row > ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row + 1
End Sub
```